# what does 如今年至及笄 mean?

Tags: translation

This is a part of a character story and while I can understand other things that are written, this part evades my grasp. In official translation it was translated as "15 years", but there are some discrepancies with other parts of the story.

Comment: This is not an independent phrase, to be meaningful to others, you need to upload more text.

Comment: 笄 （ji1), (ㄐㄧ), 音同“机” . 年至及笄

Answer (score 1):

there is as mistake happened， the correct form is "如今年至及笄”, that means "now she is 15 years old".

"及笄之年" is special term for girl who is about 15 years old. In ancient times, if a girl whose age is 15 is old enough to get engaged, she would tie her hair and wear a hairpin(及笄（之年）). 及 here means use(often not in other sentence), 笄 means a kind of hairpin.

如今: now,nowadays 年：year (years old in this place), 至：enough to (just in this sentence, if 至 followed by time point means: it's time to ..., it can be used in this sentence, but enough to is more apropos to fit the sentence).

so, the entire sentence is "nowadays, (someone omit default) is enough to 15 years old."

---*---added---*---

be faithful to the original" nowadays, (some girl Omitted default) is old enough to tie the hairpin"

as for male, here are "及冠" means tie a special kind of hat(original in ancient China) for celebrate for adult when he is 20.

Comment: The form(style) of the sentence is classical Chinese, not modern Chinese.

Comment: 笄 （ji1), (ㄐㄧ), 音同“机” .

Comment: 及笄之年， here is a mistake, 及： here is preposition,  which have no practical implications.